# Why is "Generate Signed APK" disabled in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there are a bunch of questions about errors that occur when Generate Signed APK is invoked in Android Studio.  However, I can't even get there!

I'm working with Unity and *cough cough* this is my first time trying to make an Android build.  At first I thought maybe Unity would export an Eclipse build but it seems to be more up to date than that.

Anyway, I downloaded Android Studio, and loaded the project, but the button is disabled.  I read somewhere about someone having to install gradle manually, but when I looked in the plugins folder of the app, gradle *is* there.

I thought it might be something to do with not having connected a key store but, apparently you're supposed to do that after you select Generate Signed APK.

Any ideas?  Thank you, I'm tearing my hair out.

Comment: did you ever find out why that is? I am having the same issue here...

Comment: Hi, no, I didn't.  I *think* that if you do all the digital signing within Unity with a key store then what it produces is a signed app that you can upload to Google Play (as an example), but I'm not 100% sure.